# Is ascii Text art portable?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, portability

Is ASCII Text art portable from Windows to Linux, and MAC?

Reasons it might not be:

- The consoles of the different systems use different character sets.
- The consoles use different fonts
- Some consoles might not support colors?

Is it possible that only some characters could be used to make it portable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing even remotely to do with programming.

Comment: ascii is ascii. the lower 7bit chars are pretty much universal.

Comment: @MarcB So I will be able to use the block characters?

Comment: only if they're ascii codes 0->127. anything 128+ is 'anything goes'.

Comment: @Mah He could be planning on writing an application that produces output as ASCII art. He need to know this in preparation. I've heard of print drivers that work like this.

Comment: Ok....That helps (I won't be able to use ▓ and ╔ and the like chars)

Comment: @Barmar that doesn't make it related to programming in the slightest. By your justification, I could ask where babies come from and it would be on topic, if I was planning to write a program about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If it really is ASCII art, it only uses the ASCII character set, so there should be no issue with character sets or encodings.
2. Fonts might well be an issue. ASCII art only works with fixed-width fonts, not with proportional ones.
3. I have never seen ASCII art using different colors.

All of this has nothing to do with platforms or operating systems.

Comment: _All of this has nothing to do with platforms or operating systems_ - and for that reason an answer should really not be provided (except as a comment). Questions that are off topic but have answers can sometimes be impossible to delete even after being closed.

Comment: @mah: Not sure if the question is off-topic. It does have to to with fonts, character-encodings and (somewhat) portability. I hope that my answer provides some clarification for the OP.